# Error al entrenar un modelo

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

Tengo un archivo CSV, coloco algunos datos solamente dado que tiene más de seis mil datos:

```
Form;Gloss
a;a tí
á;yo
à;aarón
aàn;abba
aarón;abel
abba;abías
abel;Abilinia
abías;abraham
abilinia;acaya
abraham;Acaz
```

Coloco ahora el código

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

    # Leer los datos de un archivo CSV con delimitador de tabulación
    data = pd.read_csv('lexmau.csv', delimiter=';')


    # Eliminar filas con valores nulos en la columna 'Gloss'
    data = data.dropna(subset=['Gloss'])

    # Separar los datos en las columnas de mazateco y español
    mazateco = data['Form']
    espanol = data['Gloss']

    # Tokenizar las oraciones
    mazateco_tokenizado = [m.split() for m in mazateco]
    espanol_tokenizado = [e.split() for e in espanol]
    print(mazateco_tokenizado)

    # Crear los conjuntos de datos de entrenamiento y prueba
    mazateco_train, mazateco_test, espanol_train, espanol_test = 
    train_test_split(mazateco_tokenizado, espanol_tokenizado, test_size=0.2)
    
    import tensorflow as tf
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Dense
    from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

    # Definir las dimensiones de los datos de entrada y salida
    mazateco_dim = len(mazateco)
    espanol_dim = len(espanol)

    # Definir los parámetros del modelo
    embedding_dim = 256
    units = 1024

    # Definir la entrada para el modelo
    encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None,))

    # Definir la capa de codificación
    encoder_embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(mazateco_dim, embedding_dim)(encoder_inputs)
    encoder_lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units, return_state=True)
    encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder_lstm(encoder_embedding)
    encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

    # Definir la entrada para el decodificador
    decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None,))

    # Definir la capa de decodificación
    decoder_embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(espanol_dim, embedding_dim)
    decoder_lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
    decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_lstm(decoder_embedding(decoder_inputs), 
    initial_state=encoder_states)
    decoder_dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(espanol_dim, activation='softmax')
    decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)

    # Definir el modelo completo
    model = tf.keras.models.Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)
    import numpy as np
    espanol_train = np.array(espanol_train)
    print(espanol_train)
    # Convertir cada lista en espanol_train en un solo string
    espanol_train_str = [' '.join(lst) for lst in espanol_train]

    # Imprimir la nueva lista resultante
    print(espanol_train_str)
    mazateco_train = np.array(mazateco_train)
    espanol_train = np.array(espanol_train)
    mazateco_test = np.array(mazateco_test)
    espanol_test = np.array(espanol_test)

    espanol_train_str = np.array(espanol_train_str)
    espanol_test = np.array(espanol_test)

    espanol_train_input = [s[:-1] for s in espanol_train_str]
    espanol_train_target = [s[1:] for s in espanol_train_str]
    espanol_test_input = espanol_test[:-1]
    espanol_test_target = espanol_test[1:]
    model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
    mazateco_train = np.array(mazateco_train)
    mazateco_test = np.array(mazateco_test)
    np.expand_dims(espanol_train_input, axis=1)

    espanol_train_input = np.array(espanol_train_input)
    espanol_train_target = np.array(espanol_train_target)
    espanol_test_input = np.array(espanol_test_input)
    espanol_test_target = np.array(espanol_test_target)

    batch_size = 64
    epochs = 100

    model.fit([mazateco_train, np.expand_dims(espanol_train_input, axis=2)], espanol_train_target, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_data=([mazateco_test, np.expand_dims(espanol_test_input, axis=2)], espanol_test_target))
```

Lo cierto que lo estoy haciendo en un Colaboratory, y me sale error en el model.fit

```
AxisError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-115-2626fa18ec49> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 model.fit([mazateco_train, np.expand_dims(espanol_train_input, axis=2)], espanol_train_target, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_data=([mazateco_test, np.expand_dims(espanol_test_input, axis=2)], espanol_test_target))

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   1389             pass
   1390     # Going via an iterator directly is slower than via list comprehension.
-> 1391     axis = tuple([normalize_axis_index(ax, ndim, argname) for ax in axis])
   1392     if not allow_duplicate and len(set(axis)) != len(axis):
   1393         if argname:

AxisError: axis 2 is out of bounds for array of dimension 2
```

Qué solución puedo aplicar aquí?
Estoy entrenando una especie de diccionario, para que cuando ingrese una oración en idioma Mazateco, me pueda dar una traducción aproximada.

Comment: DIces que el delimitador es `;` pero el ejemplo separa por espacios/tabs. Posiblemente no tienes dos columnas.

Comment: Es que el archivo lo tengo guardado como CSV delimitado por comas. Lo que pasa es que en la pregunta lo copié tal cual aparece en el excel

Comment: Recuerda que acá sólo tenemos lo que nos muestras, no sabemos nada, no imaginamos nada. ;)

Comment: Si, lo siento @Alfabravo por eso lo informo. Disculpas

Answer (score 0):

Cuando haces

```
model.fit(
    [mazateco_train, np.expand_dims(espanol_train_input, axis=2)],
    espanol_train_target, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, 
    validation_data=(
        [mazateco_test, np.expand_dims(espanol_test_input, axis=2)], 
        espanol_test_target
    )
)
```

los ejes son zero-based. Prueba usando `axis=1` EN AMBOS USOS. Y tienes que definir el batch_size y el número de epochs (tienes variables sin definir). Si uso cualquier valor (no conozco los requerimientos de tu modelo)

```
model.fit(
    [mazateco_train, np.expand_dims(espanol_train_input, axis=1)],
    espanol_train_target, batch_size=3, epochs=10, 
    validation_data=(
        [mazateco_test, np.expand_dims(espanol_test_input, axis=1)], 
        espanol_test_target
    )
)
```

Se queda en que hay un casting por ahí de String a float. Y sé que esto es porque se necesitan etiquetas numéricas para la clasificación. Algo como lo que indican en https://stackoverflow.com/a/61635080/236345.

PD. Si me da el tiempo, vuelvo a dedicarle otro rato

Comment: HHola mi estimado, ya probé con axis=1, e igual me arroja error

Comment: @JeanGotopo mismo error?

Comment: @JeanGotopo yo lo probé y me dio un error diferente... y es que en batch_size usas una variable que no está definida

Comment: Edité la pregunta, había olvidado la parte donde se definen esas variables. Está justo encima del model.fit

Comment: @JeanGotopo adivinar cómo es que estás corriendo el código hace todo infinitamente más difícil. Lo que hacemos acá es replicar el problema con el código y los datos de prueba...

Comment: Lo sinto si olvidé algunos detalles, ya está todo el código. Lo estoy corriendo tanto en Google Colaboratory como en Jupyter Notebook